# filter get and post values

Tags: php, post, filter, get

I call my main page framework_ui.php in it I require auth.php where I have a filter function.

```
function filter($data)
{
   // normalize $data because of get_magic_quotes_gpc
   $dataNeedsStripSlashes = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
   if ($dataNeedsStripSlashes) {
       $data = stripslashes($data);
   }
   // normalize $data because of whitespace on beginning and end
   $data = trim($data);
   // strip tags
   $data = strip_tags($data);
   // replace characters with their HTML entitites
   $data = htmlentities($data);
   // mysql escape string    
   $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
   return $data;
}
```

and on every page with get and post variables I do a: (and call my framework.php)

```
// filter GET values
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value);
}
// filter post
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

Will the function still operate properly if I make the above a function and call that instead on every page?

```
function filter_all() {
// filter GET values
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value);
}
// filter post
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = filter($value);
}
}
```

I understand this is not the most secure way, however I was wondering if this sort of thing was possible and wouldn't negatively effect my code.

Comment: Your `filter` function is **TERRIBLE**, applying random functions to the input barely related to "security"

Comment: Your question is not clear " I was wondering if this sort of thing was possible and wouldn't negatively effect my code." - why don't you just try it ?

Comment: Agreed with @zerkms.  That being said, you will need to return the `$get` and `$post` from the function or else they will drop out of scope.

Comment: I would but there is no way of knowing (that I know of) to check if the string is getting escaped. and the filter function is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395372/what-is-the-securest-way-to-add-html-css-js-to-mysql

Comment: @sberry you said exactly what I was thinking: if `$get` and `post` are globals - it should be declared as such, and if not - it'll live only in the function scope.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, this function I primarily use for escaping get and post variables from a form.

Comment: @Alex: 1. sanitize the data in place, **only when you need it** and only in a way it is required in a particular place. 2. use PDO with prepared statements 3. delete `filter` function

Comment: I get that you guys know a lot more than me regarding php. But I mean say I have a get variable and i want to 'secure' it from injection then i escape it mysql_real_escape_string($_get)... but if i do filter($_get) is that the same thing as it applies the escape? perhaps you could explain to me how the two are different?

Comment: @Alex: your current solution is bad. Just accept it and don't do that anymore

Comment: @Alex: because applying *random* functions in random order makes no sense. Why would you apply `mysql_real_escape_string` to a variable that won't be sent to a DB?

Comment: the variables are being sent to the database. in any case thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your filter_all() function returns nothing and it does not modify the $_GET and $_POST globals so after your function finishes to run those original variables your foreach looping through will be effectively the same. You should either manipulate $_GET/$_POST directly or global $get/$post if you plan on using them or return some combination of the two. Other than that there's nothing necessarily negative about what your planning to do.

If you are going to be doing this every time might as well not make a function and just include a file (like your framework_ui.php) which just does the loopage and filters the variables.

zerkms is correct though your filter function is not ideal in that it is not secure and in fact that mysql_real_escape_string will cause issues if you plan on re-displaying user submitted info back (among many other things).

To quote the OWASP ESAPI project page:

> Don't write your own security controls! Reinventing the wheel when it comes to developing security controls for every web application or web service leads to wasted time and massive security holes. The OWASP Enterprise Security API (ESAPI) Toolkits help software developers guard against security‐related design and implementation flaws. http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/

Comment: thanks for the owasp link, i'll have to look into it. also thanks for explaining!

Comment: No problem Alex, good luck! Also the main site which might have more resources as well is at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make some tweaks to ensure the 'filtered' values are available to the rest of your code.  There are a couple of ways to do it, marking them as `global` or returning them; probly the second option is generally considered cleaner.  Here's an example:

```
function filter_all() {
    $get  = array();
    $post = array();

    // filter GET values
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $get[$key] = filter($value);
    }
    // filter post
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $post[$key] = filter($value);
    }
    return array(
            'get'  => $get,
            'post' => $post);
}

$aFilteredInput = filter_all();
$get  = $aFilteredInput['post'];
$post = $aFilteredInput['post'];
```